# How to sort posts without featured images in the WordPress Dashboard? thanks

Tags: wp-list-table

Is there any option to sort posts by without featured images in WordPress dashboard?
(function code)

Comment: No, there is no default option for that. You'll either have to code it manually or look for a plugin that does..

Comment: Here is an article on how to code it yourself: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/12/customizing-admin-columns-wordpress/

Comment: And this is a very good plugin that does it for you: https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/